# Change WebPart Custom Properties Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I'm developing a WebPart for Sharepoint 2010. I created custom properties but i would like to change the layout. I would like that the elements below would look like the default elements(spacing and padding etc).

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        PartPanel = new UpdatePanel();
        PartPanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;

        label2 = new Label();
        label2.Text = "Choose component <br/><br/>";
        ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = "ddl";
        ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        ddl.EnableViewState = false;
        ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
        ddl.Items.Insert(0 ,"--Select--");
        ddl.Items.Insert(1, "a");
        ddl.Items.Insert(2, "b");

        label1 = new Label();
        label1.Text = "";

        channels = new DropDownList();
        channels.ID = "a";
        channels.Visible = false;
        channels.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 15);
        channels.DataBind();

        videos = new TextBox();
        videos.Visible = false;

        PartPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(label2);
        PartPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(ddl);
        PartPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(label1);
        PartPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(videos);
        PartPanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(channels);

        this.Controls.Add(PartPanel);
        base.CreateChildControls();

    }
```

what to do here? As you noticed i added a few break lines but that doesn't do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

check what CSS classes the standard properties has and add those to your controls CssClass property.

Regards,
Martin